# Double Wide Views Table

Tags: views

I have a table listing that shows the Item # and a View/Print/Download link to open a PDF datasheet in a new tab.  Right now I have like 3 or 4 in the system but in time I will have like 700-800 of them and the columns take up less than half the width of the page and although I have been looking I can't find a way to create two columns

I don't care whether the data goes

```
CH098 View     CH099 View
CH100 View     CH101 View
CH102 View     CH103 View
```

or

```
CH098 View     CH101 View
CH099 View     CH102 View
CH100 View     CH103 View
```

Does anyone know if there is a module for views that I missed that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using *Views*, you've got everything you need.  You just need to set the Display Format to Grid, and set it to Show Fields, as in the following example from editing a view.

And to display more than one field in each Grid "cell", you will need to add a `Global: Custom Text` field to combine the fields for display. (Change the *Content: Title* and *Content: Link* fields used in these example to your fields.)

See the Image of *Custom Text Settings* (below) for an example of how to combine the fields. The Replacement patterns shows the fields available to be combined.

In the settings for each field, set *Content: Title* and *Content: Link* fields to be excluded from display, and set the *Global: Custom text* to NOT be excluded.

Oh, yeah... these images are from Views 3.x.

**View settings:**
  [image: Image of View settings]

Click the `Settings` link next to 'Grid' to set the 'Number of columns'. You can also set the display Alignment to Horizontal or Vertical.

**Grid settings:**
  [image: Image of Grid settings]

**Global Custom Text selection:**
  [image: Image of Global Custom Text selection]

**Custom Text Settings:**
  [image: Image of Custom Text Settings]

Comment: while your answer works I realize that I forgot to mention that I wanted headers on my columns although this works fine I guess